# Change message "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." to actual days

Tags: feature-request, support, rejected-edits

I have been banned automatically for edits before 2 days, So before 2 days it was showing **`"Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days."`**.

I again tried today for editing tag wiki to see how many days left for me to continue editing tag wiki, and boom I again received **`"Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days."`**

I wonder it's a static message given or whenever I try to edit tag wiki it will extend ?

Is it possible to have real count of days, i.e. how many days left for able to edit again.

Please bear with me if this sounds stupid.

Comment: [Your page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164564/jennis) includes some nice recursion.

Comment: You'll know the answer to your question in five days at the lastest. :-)

Comment: can you edit question now after 7 days limit? I also got banned from editing.