# Trying to improve a tag wiki while blocked causes incorrect 'This post has been deleted'

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

**Scenario**:

- Assume you are a user suffering some type of being banned, where if you try to **suggest an edit**. You will not be able to do so, and instead you get a message like "You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history."
- Navigate to anything similar to this:

  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation
- Using the link "[improve wiki tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/9)" you will arrive at a page containing (only) this message:

  > This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed
- Change 'reputation' to any other valid tag, eg 'new-user', and the same scenario can be repeated for that tag also (though its 'improve wiki tag' also varies of course).

**Related feature requests**:

["improve tag wiki" should be greyed out like "edit" while banned from editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194179) appears to me as a way to prevent this scenario from happening.

**Possible duplicate questions:**

To avoid creating a duplicate question, I searched for [misleading message wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=misleading%20message%20wiki). The search results do not contain any question titles that seem related to my question here.

I also think this issue is not a duplicate of "[When tag wiki excerpt does not exist, but tag wiki does, some messages/activities are misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/when-tag-wiki-excerpt-does-not-exist-but-tag-wiki-does-some-messages-activitie?s=1%7C4.4663)".

**My Questions**:

- It appears to me that this message is at least misleading, if not wrong. No?
- Shouldn't it display a normal error message indicating that the user is not allowed to edit due to an account restriction?
- Why would it think that the post is deleted?

Comment: @ Pierre While *you* may be a fairly new user and (I assume) not a native English speaker, your bug report here is not actually about new users or non-English speakers in general. Tags exist to categorize the question's content, not the user posting it.

Comment: @animuson ok, 'that' is why, thank you, makes sense. Must be I missed that in the tour and/or that I did not study the help well enough yet. Also, with 'that' in mind, about the non-english-speakers tag: it appears to me that it's excerpt content  needs updating, which says 'The tag non-english-speakers is for questions about posts made by non-english speakers and the issues surrounding these posts and users.' because this question was posted by a Dutch speaking poster, who knew  that that info should NOT be part question. I might suggest a wiki excerpt edit whenever I'm allowed to do so.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens It doesn't need updating.  It says it "is for ***questions about*** posts made by non-english speakers," not "posts made by non-english speakers."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that the misleading message is because of my assumption "***user is banned somehow***".

And therefor the message should rather be something like

> ... - no more edits are allowed

(pick whatever fits to replace the '... -' suffix I suggested here).

Maybe add some extra indication like "because your userid has been banned" (or some variation of that). Better still: consider these refinements:

1. include the applicable values for **rejects** and **approvals** indicators mentioned in one of the answers in [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392) (which appears to be about questions and answers, not tags). In there it says:

   > When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity. If (rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5, you will be auto-banned.
2. try to rework the (apparent) hardcoded value of "7" (in "7 days") in actual days left, similar to what is suggested in [Change message "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." to actual days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154785) (which appears to be about questions and answers, not tags). That could also partially address the feature request about [Why is the ban for too many rejected edits so lengthy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91323/) ...  Because in the given scenario where the message was shown after 2 days, it would have been 5 days ... (7-2=5 ...).